# I added a third task to my DAG, but it down't show up

Tags: airflow

I am new to Airflow and have so far succeeded in getting my first two tasks running in a DAG.

But when I add the third task (almost identical to the first one -- both BashOperator tasks) it doesn't show up when I try to test it (task not found) and it's missing when I run

`airflow list_tasks mydag`

Here's the task that works:

```
START_TASK = BashOperator(
    task_id='start_task',
    bash_command="echo 'Successfully Started'",
    dag=dedup_dag
)
```

Here's the **ignored** task:

```
mv_task = BashOperator(
    task_id = "randomized_name_task",
    bash_command = "mkdir -p /data/airflow/keywordstep1; gsutil cp gs://airflow-dev-test/keywordstep1/000000_0 /data/airflow/keywordstep1/infile",
    dag_id = dedup_dag
)
```

Any ideas on this?

Comment: Without sharing code it won't be possible to answer your question. See "Help others reproduce the problem" in https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and share relevant code.

Comment: Agreed ^ But a common mistake is using the same task_id as another task in your DAG, may be part of the problem

Answer (score 1):

The problem is a basic typo:

In your ignored task:

```
mv_task = BashOperator(
    task_id = "randomized_name_task",
    bash_command = "mkdir -p /data/airflow/keywordstep1; gsutil cp gs://airflow-dev-test/keywordstep1/000000_0 /data/airflow/keywordstep1/infile",
    dag_id = dedup_dag
)
```

`dag_id` paramater is used when you define a dag.

In a task that we want to add in a dag, we use `dag` paramater.

So your code should be:

```
mv_task = BashOperator(
    task_id = "randomized_name_task",
    bash_command = "mkdir -p /data/airflow/keywordstep1; gsutil cp gs://airflow-dev-test/keywordstep1/000000_0 /data/airflow/keywordstep1/infile",
    dag = dedup_dag
)
```

Also, I would recommend using [PEP 8: Function and Variable Names:](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names) guide, to be consistent:

> Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by
> underscores as necessary to improve readability.
>
> Variable names follow the same convention as function names.

Comment: Thanks ... I looked at this 10 times and didn't see it; too busy I guess!

Comment: Oh it happens! You are most welcome :)